# Writing a VBS file using batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Hello i need help with my batch file im working on i'm trying to get a batch file to write a vbs for the input box

```
`echo B = InputBox("PLEASE ENTER PROMETHEUS PASSWORD") > B14.vbs
echo if B <> "jp030700" then >> B14.vbs
echo h=msgBox("INCORRECT",16,"Prometheus - Verify") >> B14.vbs
echo Set ws=CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> B14.vbs
echo    ws.Run ("TASKKILL.exe /F /IM cmd.exe"), 0 , True >> B14.vbs
echo wscript.Quit >> B14.vbs
echo end if >> B14.vbs
echo if B = "jp030700" then >> B14.vbs
echo end if >> B14.vbs
pause`
```

i tried to write this to B14.vbs as you can see all i get is this in the file created     `B = InputBox("PLEASE ENTER PROMETHEUS PASSWORD")`     and nothing else please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. When you want to print an actual `<` or `>` in batch instead of using it as a redirection symbol, you need to use `^` to escape the character.

Change the second line of your script to `echo if B ^<^> "jp030700" then >> B14.vbs`

Comment: @Somperson99 - No problem. If my answer is the one you're going with, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: It says i need to wait 3 min. i will check it in 3 min thanks